ESLint migration issue while converting extends to v9
I'm trying to convert my .eslintrc.cjs to eslint.config.js with migration of ESLint.
My current config file has
extends: ['eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'prettier'],

And I tried to convert this as follows according to the migration guide and documentation
import eslint from "@eslint/js";

export default [

    {
        plugins: {
            eslint: eslint
        },
        rules: {
            'eslint': "warn"
        }
    }
];

When I run lint I get the following error.
 @hmp/vue3@1.0.0 lint
> npx eslint

npm warn config ignoring workspace config at D:PATH\workspaces\vue3/.npmrc

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.15.0

TypeError: Key "rules": Key "eslint": Could not find "eslint" in plugin "@".
    at throwRuleNotFoundError (D:\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\rule-validator.js:66:11)
    at RuleValidator.validate (D:\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\rule-validator.js:147:17)
    at new Config (D:\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config.js:228:27)
    at [finalizeConfig] (D:\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\flat-config-array.js:216:16)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfigWithStatus (D:\node_modules\@eslint\config-array\dist\cjs\index.cjs:1178:55)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfig (D:\\node_modules\@eslint\config-array\dist\cjs\index.cjs:1196:15)
    at entryFilter (D:\\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint-helpers.js:282:40)
    at async NodeHfs.<anonymous> (file:///D:/node_modules/@humanfs/core/src/hfs.js:574:24)
    at async NodeHfs.walk (file:///D:/node_modules/@humanfs/core/src/hfs.js:614:3)
    at async globSearch (D:\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint-helpers.js:323:26)
npm error Lifecycle script `lint` failed with error:
npm error code 2
npm error path D:PATH\workspaces\vue3
npm error workspace @hmp/vue3@1.0.0
npm error location D:PATH\workspaces\vue3
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npx eslint
```



What is the issue?

@EstusFlask Sorry, I updated the error

Can you clarify what's the intention? You have no counterpart to "extends", and 'eslint': "warn" results in an error because there's no such rule. Rules are these https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/ . I'd suggest to just create a new vue project and borrow the config from there

Here what I'm trying to do is converting the eslint to v9.
The one given at the top is the extends in v8 and I tried to convert that to v9. Not sure how extends can be converted into v9.
@EstusFlask

See https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/ , it has eslint.config.js examples aka flat config). Proceed from the recommended approach on this plugin as it's important to make .vue files work. Notice the use of ts.config() helper, it helps. Since that config file already contain most things you need, you'll need to add prettierRecommended from 'eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended' the same way as other plugin configs

Since you're using typescript-eslint and Vue, I'd suggest going off the docs from https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser:
import js from '@eslint/js'
import eslintPluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue'
import ts from 'typescript-eslint'

export default ts.config(
  js.configs.recommended,
  ...ts.configs.recommended,
  ...eslintPluginVue.configs['flat/recommended'],
  {
    files: ['*.vue', '**/*.vue'],
    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
      }
    }
  }
)

The issues in the config you've posted are:

eslint (imported from @eslint/js) doesn't need to be listed in plugins. ESLint's JS rules are built into ESLint. plugins is used to load in external plugins that aren't built-in, such as typescript-eslint and Vue.
rules: { 'eslint': 'warn' } does not make sense. rules is an object mapping rule names to their severities and options. eslint is not the name of a rule.

This is why you're getting the TypeError: ESLint is saying there's no built-in (under the default plugin namespace, '@') rule named 'eslint'



